# Cannot change organization location to Australia East in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

The bot does not show Australia East as target region. Can anyone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLh16.png)

Answer (score 0):

Totally, we has 8 regions: `South Brazil`, `Australia East`, `South India`, `West Europe`, `East Asia`, `Canada Central`, `Uk` and `Central US`.

Once you could not see one region displayed in drop list, this only because this region is the one your organization is locate in.

In another word, the organization you want to move, its region is locating in `Australia East` now. That's why you could not see value in drop list.

---

For sample, my org is located in `East Asia`:

[image]

and you can see there's no `East Asia` display as choice:

[image]

Comment: Hi, my account is in correct region. But the organization that I'm admin now was created by a user who`s region was East US. But no longer work with us. When bot ask for the user account I think it checking my user account region rather than the Organization region. Any ideas to solve this.

Comment: @TharinduThudugala Would you mind share the org name here? I can check it from our backend.(For security, I will notify you to delete it once I know it’s name)

Comment: @TharinduThudugala, I saw you have ticket to our business support. Also, I saw you raised the region move request in 2/14 and we notify you with the mail about we have receive your request on move to Australia east. So, select australia east is available then, but failed now? In addition, we did not check the org region as owner's account region. Just in your scenario, its move does not finish successfully and completely.

Comment: the case is been worked on. I was asked one time see if it's been fixed and I can see target region Australia East. But no luck yet. Also the bot does not ask me for organization, It only ask me to log in, I have another organization that is in  Australia East

Comment: @TharinduThudugala, Could not select organization, does the bot display the organization name automatically? In addition, you should received one mail which about we could not proceed the move due to backend ongoing deployments on your desired time period. Did you follow that choose new available windows?

Comment: Thank you @Merlin Liang, Issue is fixed now